# NPAPI plugins in JavaFX webview

Tags: webview, javafx, npapi

Is it possible to load NPAPI plugins in JavaFX Webview, which enables to have a web browser inside a Java Program?

Answer (score 0):

No.

WebView does not support plugin technology.